# Resharper's settings often reset spontaneusly

Tags: resharper, settings

Resharper's settings often reset spontaneously. This happens almost always after Visual Studio has been restarted, but I don't found exact regularity.

This continually repeats on every Visual Studio on every machine I am work.

This is corrected by pressing "Apply Scheme" inside "Resharper options -> Keyboard & Menus".

But why is this happening and how to prevent it from happening again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you have a non-English keyboard language installed on a machine, you may probably experience this issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-449737. Visual Studio can forget custom shortcuts if you change keyboard languages between launching/closing Visual Studio instances. 
You may try reproducing the same issue on any custom shortcuts as described in ticket's comment:

> 1. Suspend ReSharper. Restart VS.
> 2. English is an input language. Assign shortcut "Ctrl+/" to the Edit.NavigateTo command using Tools | Options | Keyboard (see 1.png)
> 3. Restart VS. Shortcut is assigned (see 2.png)
> 4. Close VS. Switch to a non-English input language. Start VS. The shortcut becomes "Ctrl+\" (see 3.png and 4.png)
> 5. Close VS. Your language is still an input language. Start VS. Shortcut is lost (see 5.png and 6.png). It's 100% reproducible for Russian. You can use any VS command instead Edit.NavigateTo, it does not matter. May be you can try to apply the shortcut in French and then switch to English.

Comment: I think you are right, looks like Microsoft's bug. Shortcut is not lost, like mentoined in point 5, but other points are reproduced. Unfortunately, considering that the bug was find almost 5 years ago, nothing inspires hope that it will ever be fixed...